# Native plugin with Unity3d Mac OSX Dll notfoundexception

Tags: macos, plugins, mono, unity-game-engine, dllnotfoundexception

I am trying to integrate a 3rd party native plugin with **unity3D**. In order to use it i made a c# plugin as a wrapper dll. The plugin works fine with PC standalone when i copy the plugin binaries manually to build folder along with my EXE file.I have used debug configuration for the plugin build process.

Problem is :

- when i make a mac OS X build, i am getting ***DllNotFoundException***. My c# plugin file is in the app located at "\Contents\Data\Managed" along with other unity related plugins which means unity is recognizing my wrapper plugin but not copying the native plugins.

Things already tried :

- I copied the native plugins also in the *Assets/Plugins/* folder so as they are also included in build, but unity didn't include them in build.
- I tried putting my native plugin in "*\Contents\Data\Managed*" folder and also in other folders in the app,still it was not able to find the dll.
- I tried putting the dylib file which came with the native plugin, also along with my wrapper plugin but it didn't work.
- I tried to do a dllmap in the config file at "*\Contents\Data\Managed\etc\mono*" using
   also, but it didn't work.

I am out of ideas. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me to add a dll map to the mono config file found here:
Your.app/Contents/Data/Managed/etc/mono/config

I added the following :

```
<dllmap dll="phidget21.dll" target="/Library/Frameworks/Phidget21.framework/Versions/Current/Phidget21" />
```

Make sure that the Phidget21.framework exists in /Library/Frameworks..